# Angular ng-click function param not works

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

When i use the ng-click inside ng-repeat ,the function param is not work when i click the button.but in the dom is works .

```js
 $scope.Modify=function(a){
  console.log("Edit"+a);
 }
 $scope.Del=function(a,b){
  console.log("DEL:"+a);
  Metronic.ajax("delete","vt/"+a,{},true,Metronic.handleResponse,delValue,b);
 }
```

```html
<tr ng-repeat="vr in data">
 <td>{{$index}}</td>
 <td>{{vr.type_name}}</td>
 <td>{{vr.sort}}</td>
 <td>
 <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" ng-click="Modify('{{vr.vt_id}}')">Edit</a>
 <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" ng-click="Del($index)">Del</a>
 </td>
</tr>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the curly braces when you are passing a variable into a function. Change `ng-click="Modify('{{vr.vt_id}}')">` to `ng-click="Modify(vr.vt_id)">`

Comment: But the dom has not compile to the variable in this way.         <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" ng-click="Modify(vr.vt_id)">Edit</a>